# How can I get my terminals / shells to have custom designs in it?

Tags: command-line, scripts, customization, c++, c

How can I add fun stuff to my terminal so I have extra zazz for when I break every thing every day! :D I'm  learning C / C++ and think root projects and custom terminals would be fun way to practice since it's what im in to.

```
                                                  / \                 / \
    __  ___    ___     ______      __  ___  ___  |   |_______/\______|   |
   /  \ | |    | |     | |_  \    /  \ | |  | |  _\_/_________________\_/_
  / __ \| |    | |     | | \  \  / __ \| |__| |_/                         \_
 | |  | | |    | |     | |  \  \| |  | |_____ |_B-E-A_M-M-E-U-P-S-C-O-T-T-Y_|
 | |  | | |    | |     | |  /  /| |  | |    | | \_________________________/
 | |  | | |____| |_____| |_/  / | |  | |____| |       \ \   |__|   / /
 |_|  |_|______|_______|_____/  |_|  |_|______|        \ \ //  \\ / /
                                                        | /|    |\ |
                                                         |_*\__/*_|
                                                          \______/
```

Comment: Your question is actually pretty broad and I'm sure it's a duplicate of another existing question. It might be better if you narrow it down to a more specific task you want to achieve. Nonetheless, I've posted an answer, let me know what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No coding necessary.

1. Save whatever the logo you like to a txt file somewhere in your home folder.
2. Open with text editor a config file for your shell. In my case for `mksh` shell that would be `.mkshrc` , for `bash` - `.bashrc`
3. Add command `cat myawesomestuff.txt` at the end of the file.
4. Relaunch shell or run `source .bashrc` (in my case `source .mkshrc`)

Bellow is the example. I've another program, `fortune` running on each start of the shell, so don't be surprised by the quotes

```
$ nano awesome.txt

$ nano .mkshrc 

$ source .mkshrc
Q:  What's the difference between the 1950's and the 1980's?
A:  In the 80's, a man walks into a drugstore and states loudly, "I'd
    like some condoms," and then, leaning over the counter, whispers,
    "and some cigarettes."
                                                  / \                 / \
    __  ___    ___     ______      __  ___  ___  |   |_______/\______|   |
   /  \ | |    | |     | |_  \    /  \ | |  | |  _\_/_________________\_/_
  / __ \| |    | |     | | \  \  / __ \| |__| |_/                         \_
 | |  | | |    | |     | |  \  \| |  | |_____ |_B-E-A_M-M-E-U-P-S-C-O-T-T-Y_|
 | |  | | |    | |     | |  /  /| |  | |    | | \_________________________/
 | |  | | |____| |_____| |_/  / | |  | |____| |       \ \   |__|   / /
 |_|  |_|______|_______|_____/  |_|  |_|______|        \ \ //  \\ / /
                                                        | /|    |\ |
                                                         |_*\__/*_|
                                                          \______/
```

Comment: Great, looks funny :)